# problem in understanding a part of a code

Tags: c++

the code below is a part of a program which makes some integer sets by using class.
the member variable is called set which is a boolean vector and set[i]=true if i is in set.
now we want to have the members of a set in a string in the way that each member seprates by ','.
for example if in main function we have `IntegerSet A` and the members of A are 1,2,3 ; by using `toString.A()` we should have `{1,2,3}` in output.
I have the code of this part of program but my problem is that I don't know what `bool first=true` exactly do and how by using it the compiler understand that we mean what?
I would appreciate if anyone can help me.

```
std::string IntegerSet::toString(IntegerSet)
{
    std::string str;
    bool first = true;
    str += '{';
    for (int i = 0; i <= limit; i++)
    {
        if (set[i])
        {
            if (!first)
                str += ",";
            else
                first = false; 
            str += std::to_string(i);
                
        }
    }
    str += '}';
    return str;
}
```

Comment: `bool first=true` assigns the value `true` to the boolean variable `first`.

Comment: `if (!first)` prevents adding a comma before the 1st value added to the string.

Comment: @ScottHunter What an on-point answer fo SO.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ first is a separate part of the set. How does It understand if we are at the 1st value or not?

Comment: @pantea Because `first` is set to `true` for the 1st iteration of the loop, and it's not part of the set itself but a separate boolean variable.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I can't understand the connection between `if(set[i])` and `if(!first)` in a loop

Comment: @pantea there's no connection actually.